# PHP push values to nested array

Tags: php, arrays, object

i have the created the following object array in php

```
$treeData[] = (object) array(
    "name"=> "A",
    "children" => [
        [
            "name"=> "A1", 
            "children"=> [ 
                [ 
                    "name"=> "A1.1",
                    "children"=> [ 
                        [
                            "name"=> "A1.1.1",
                            "children"=> [ 
                                ....
```

I'm trying to push new values inside the children of `A1.1.1` based on below condition:

```
foreach ($treeData as $value) {
    if ($value->name == 'A') {
        $value->name[][] = (object) array(
                                           "name"=> "ChildA", 
                                           "children"=> ""
                                    );
        break;
    }
}
```

**But it's giving me an error**

Expected result should match as below example:

```
$treeData[] = (object) array(
    "name"=> "A",
    "children" => [
        [
            "name"=> "A1",
            "children"=> [ [
                "name"=> "A1.1",
                "children"=> [ [
                    "name"=> "A1.1.1",
                    "children"=> [ 
                        [
                            "name"=> "ChildA",
                            "children"=> [ [ 
                                "name"=> "ChildA1"
                            ] ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "name"=> "ChildA",
                            "children"=> [ [
                                "name"=> "ChildA2"
                            ] ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ] ]
            ] ]
        ]
   ]);
```

What I'm doing wrong here or any way to achieve this in different approach

The error I'm getting:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings "

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting for a more comprehensive understanding of its execution? :)

Comment: i have added the error

Comment: I think you are trying to force an array to an object attribute that is a string. You do not want to push it to `$value->name` but rather to `$value->children` if I am not mistaken

Comment: ok let me try it out

Comment: @DiogoSanto if i want to access children inside "name"=> "A1.1.1" how should i do it? i have written following foreach loop  but give me error  $testresult = [];
            foreach ($treeData as $value) {
               
                if($value->name == 'A'){

                   $testresult = $value->children->name;

                }
            }

Comment: If you want to keep adding children to your children and always making sure you add it to the last available position, you can do this with a `do while` loop. Is this your intent? I can write an answer for it. I can also provide you an OOP way to achieve this but would modify your code quite a bit :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you getting the error as you do: `$value->name[][]`. Notice the name is a string so you ccannot use `[]` (array append operator) on it.

I would have take the recursive approach if I were you. Consider the following pseudo code:

```
function addChild($root, $addToName, $nameToAdd) {
    if ($root->name == $addToName)
        $root->children[] =  (object) array("name"=> $nameToAdd, "children"=> []);
    else 
        foreach($root->children as $child)
            addChild($child, $addToName, $nameToAdd);
}
```

And now call is with: `addChild($treeData, 'A', "ChildA")`